# Import Users in Salesforce Error when User licenses limit exceeded

Tags: error-messages, licenses, etl, data-import, talend

With Talend Open Studio for Data Integration, the tSalesforceOutputBulkExec component is used to import users in Salesforce.

I tested the import of 1000 new users whith only 30 user licences remaining on Salesforce to check what happens.
A log in Salesforce is activated to log the events.
The import stops very quickly, no user is created and there is no error message in the log or on the Talend execution tab of the job.
This is embarrasing because I would like to have an alert if such a case happens.

How can I get an alert message in Salesforce ?

Comment: Resolved: get the rejected records on the Reject flow of tSalesforceOutputBulkExec component (as for any other object).